# Using try finally in for await is a good option?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a need to loop and wait for the modified result at the end of the `await` function call.

What would be the best option to wait for all the execution and only after completing the loop, return the result?

```
try {
    for await (var [i, object] of tablesArchive.data.entries()) {
        if (Object.keys(object).length === 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Busca IDs de relacoes existentes
        await this.getIdByRalations(tablesArchive, object, async (newObject) => {
            where = { [whereByProperty]: newObject[whereByProperty] };
            // Atualiza ou cria o registro na base de dados
            const registro = await this.upsertWithWhere(app, tablesArchive.modelName, where, newObject);
            tablesArchive.data[i].id = registro.id;
        });
    }
 } finally {
    console.log('FINALLY ');
    return tablesArchive.data;
 }
```

In the above case, I need to modify the `tablesArchive.data` object and only after going through all the indexes, and update the information. I want to call the return with all the modifications.

Comment: What does try/finally have to do with this?

Comment: You could skip the `try`/`finally` and just run the for loop, followed by the code you want to run after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't strictly need finally. Your use of await already causes the code to 'wait' until it's complete to execute the last 2 statements.

The specific case for why you might need finally, is if your `try` block you might get an exception and you want to make sure that the code in the finally block is always executed, exception or not.

I don't think this is something you need to add by default whenever there is potential of an exception being thrown. The question is, what do you want to do in case of exception? I think the default way to handle this is to let the exception throw and roll back the stack and only get caught by the first thing that can do something with it.

There is a specific case where I *always* want a finally block, when I'm doing database related stuff in a connection and I need to release the connection whether an exception was thrown or not:

```
try {
  const conn = pool.getConnection();
  await conn.query('...');
  await conn.query('...');
} finally {
   // Always release, error or not
   conn.release();
}
```

The above block of code is reasonably common in my source, but it's only because there is a specific thing I want to *regardless* of an exception happening or not.

Comment: The problem is when I call the asynchronous function inside the for.

Without the finally try to execute, the node does not wait for the return ...
Only using try finally solved my problem.
But I wanted other opinions and ways of solving the problem.

Comment: @PedroFelipeEliasDeSouza it looks like the `getIdByRalations() ` is a callback-style function. Can you convert it to a promise-based function? That would be my approach. `finally` won't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the try/catch inside the for loop and in the catch block, just log the error. Then it will continue running, and you can put your return statement right after the for loop.

```
for (var [i, object] of tablesArchive.data.entries()) {
  try {
    if (Object.keys(object).length === 0) {
      continue;
    }

    // Busca IDs de relacoes existentes
    await this.getIdByRalations(tablesArchive, object, async (newObject) => {
        where = { [whereByProperty]: newObject[whereByProperty] };
        // Atualiza ou cria o registro na base de dados
        const registro = await this.upsertWithWhere(app, tablesArchive.modelName, where, newObject);
        tablesArchive.data[i].id = registro.id;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
return tablesArchive.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here take a look at the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) API.

Short summary: you provide an array of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and wait until all Promises in this arrays are finished.

With your example I would do it like this:

```
var promises = []
for await (var [i, object] of tablesArchive.data.entries()) {
    if (Object.keys(object).length === 0) {
        continue;
    }

    // I changed this line here
    // just push every async function to the promises array
    promises.push(this.getIdByRalations(tablesArchive, object, async (newObject) => {
        where = { [whereByProperty]: newObject[whereByProperty] };
        // Atualiza ou cria o registro na base de dados
        const registro = await this.upsertWithWhere(app, tablesArchive.modelName, where, newObject);
        tablesArchive.data[i].id = registro.id;
    }));
}

return await Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    console.log('All promises are finished')
    return tablesArchive.data
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Error occured in Promises.all: ' + err)
}).finally(() => {
    console.log('All promises Finished')
})
```